# css selector for last div with a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this situation:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="pagination-bar"></div>
 <div class="article"></div>
 [..]
 <div class="article"></div>
 <div class="pagination-bar"></div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.article {
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

What if I want the pagination-bar close to the last "article" div without the 20px margin?

**UPDATED** [see the pagination-bar both on the top and to the end of the container div]

Answer (score 5):

You can have it like this, also compatible with IE7

```
div.article + div.article {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

This adds the margin on top except for the very first article.

Comment: Still applies to your update, if you also want the first "pagination-bar" close to the first "article".

Comment: This works, and after the update is a much better answer than mine is. *deleting*

Comment: it is still working if I have a variable number of article divs?

Comment: Yes, it does. The selector is to be interpreted as this: "Apply a margin of 20px on top of each div with class article that is *immediately* preceded by a div with class article". This selects all the article divs except the first one. This will work for an infinite amount of articles, it's just important that the articles are not interrupted by a div with another class. As long as that sequence is not interrupted, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.container > div:nth-last-child(2) + .pagination-bar { color: red; }
```

`:nth-last-child` will give you the second to last element in the container and the `+` selector will give you the adjacent element with class `.pagination-bar`.

Here's my test: http://jsfiddle.net/gYM7x/

With that said, browser support is limited for this pseudo class.

Comment: not working.it looks like ".article:last-child" it is the issue

Comment: It may be that the browser you're using doesn't support :last-child. It's still not reliable across all browsers. To fix this, check out  http://selectivizr.com/ to add the needed support to inferior browsers.

Comment: This won't work because you're misunderstanding `:last-child`. It matches the last child of its parent element. `.article:last-child` will never match because `<div class="pagination-bar">` is the last element.

Comment: Gotcha. I've updated my answer to one that works with the given HTML structure. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
div.container div.article:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

I don't think you've worded the question correctly. By the looks of it there is no margin on the .pagination-bar you actually want to remove the margin-bottom from the last article div so the answer above that adds + .pagination-bar may not be working because it's targeting the wrong element. Try it without the + .pagination-bar

Comment: Your answer won't work for the same reason I gave in a comment on @Jesse Bunch's answer.

Comment: scratch that. tested doesn't work. Although the answer below is smart. I would use that one. (using margin-top/first-child instead)

Answer (score 0):

Using the :last-child selector is the correct way as others have said, but according to: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html this CSS selector is not supported in IE 5.5, 6, 7, or 8.